# Assign jade variable to Angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug

In my application, I'm using NodeJS, Express in the backend and Angular in the frontend. I'm also using Jade template engine.

jade obtains a variable called "adv" by this code.

```
      res.render('page',{adv:result[0]})
```

In controller.js (for angular)

```
        $scope.content = [];
```

I would like to do something like

```
        form(ng-init="content=#{adv}") 

            h5 {{"content" + content}}
```

i.e. assign that jade variable to the scope. It is not working. I could use http.get and get the content directly to angular scope, but just wondering if it is possible to do this

Thanks

Comment: why don't you say `$scope.adv = result[0]`?

Comment: Do you get any errors? What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @Mritunjay - using res.render('page',{$scope.content:result[0]}) gives "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: @ivarni - 
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$parse/syntax?p0=Object&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%5D%5D&p2=17&p3=content%3D%5Bobject

only "content" string is displayed

Comment: The error hints that `form(ng-init="content=#{adv}")` ends up as `<form ng-init="content=[object]">` so it looks like there are two problems at play here. First, jade seems to render `result[0]` as a JSON object and not a string (maybe try to stringify it?) and second I am pretty sure you need to use single-quotes with `ng-init` if you want to assign a constant and not a variable.

Comment: Using single-quotes gave the same error.
I have to access the object's properties- so stringify is not possible.

Comment: Used stringify, gave the same error. 
But on assigning the stringify(#{adv}) to another variable and using that in ng-init worked.It even parsed the string and stored the object in 'content'.
Seems object assignment is not possible in ng-init.
 
Thanks.

Comment: Happy if I managed to help though it sounds like you solved it mainly on your own. You can post your solution as an answer if you want. It could be helpful for other people who have the same issue and end up coming here from google. Answering your own questions is perfectly fine (and even encouraged) on this site.

Comment: Not enough reputation- did it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked.

```
    - var str_adv = JSON.stringify(adv)

    form(ng-init="content = #{str_adv}")
```

or even (where getContent is a function defined in controller doing the same thing)

```
    form(ng-init="getContent(#{str_adv})")
```

Both these also parsed the string and stored the object in 'content'

But directly using

```
    form(ng-init="content = JSON.stringify(#{adv})")
```

gives the same error

It seems assigning objects in ng-init is not possible.

Thanks @ivarni for the hint about stringify

Comment: This doesn't work for me :( My code is `ng-init="balance = #{balance}"`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could also use it like this:

`form(ng-init="content = #{JSON.stringify(adv)}")`